# Не меняется http на https в вордпресс

Tags: wordpress

В админке вордпресса указываю адрес wordpress и адрес сайта

```
https://site.ru
```

В админку нельзя зайти так как пишет слишком много редиректов. Сайт работает, но все стили с http, т.е. *get_template_directory_uri()* выдает http://site.ru  вместо https://site.ru.

Выключаю все плагины, ставлю тему по умолчанию, обновляю вордпресс, удаляю .htaccess ничего не меняется.

В файле *wp-config.php* пишу:

```
define('WP_HOME','https://site.ru');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://site.ru');
```

Изменений нет.

Вывожу на сайте для проверки:
С WP_HOME проблем нет, выводится "https://site.ru"
А вот *get_site_url* выводит: "http://site.ru" без "s".

Меняю

```
define('WP_SITEURL','https://sItE.rU');
```

И *get_site_url* выводит: "http://sItE.rU" с горбами, но всё равно без "https".

В function.php прописываю

```
update_option('siteurl','https://site.ru');
```

не помогает.

Почему режется https ?

Comment: [Кратко](https://searchengines.guru/showthread.php?p=15859834#post15859834) и [подробно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress/767562#767562)

Comment: @SeVlad , это другая проблема. У меня "get_site_url()" и "get_template_directory_uri()" выводят без https, хотя указан define('WP_SITEURL','с https');

Answer (score 1):

Прописал в function.php

```
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
```

Примерный смысл, что функции резали https, потому что там использовалась функция is_ssl(), которая говорит, что нет ssl. Это из-за особенностей хостинга.